# Change nautilus items' vertical spacing in list mode

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, nautilus

#### Question:

How to change the vertical spacing between items when displayed as a list in Nautilus in Ubuntu 18.04?
Too much space is lost in my humble opinion.

Here is a direct comparison of the zoom level 4 (from zoom level 1 = smallest possible icons) between Ubuntu 18.04 (left) and 16.04 (right):

[image: comparison of nautilus zoom level 3]

Comment: the comparison you made is not directly related to one point that is vertical spacing. the size of the text and folders are also varying.

Comment: Yes, indeed it changed aswell, but like 1 pixel for text and folder on this image when I compare. But the spacing changed a lot compared!

Comment: i guess its difficult to do this.. scaling may be possible..when you select any folder, observe the orange background.., select one folder below it..both borders are in one line..meaning orange border height is the element here. i am trying to get it.. but difficult..

Comment: You can't unfortunatelly, I guess, apart from changing the source code.

Comment: yes.. with the gtk file i could only manage to increase the gap betweem rows...source code is the only option then..

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow [the instructions here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/Inspector) to enable the GTK Inspector shortcut key.
2. Open the GTK app with the ugly spacing and open the view with the ugly lists.
3. Hit CTRL+SHIFT+D to open the inspector, then use the inspect button and the Objects tab to discover some useful CSS selectors for the offending list items.
4. In the case of Nautilus, we have ugly list spacing like this in 2023:

[image: ugly Nautilus list spacing]

5. Using the inspector, you can infer that a CSS `margin` is applied to each `row` of each `listview`, and that `listview` is indirectly contained by an object with class `nautilus-list-view`
6. You can additionally see CSS `padding` applied to each cell, with the cells all given the same CSS ID `NautilusViewCell`.
7. Using the CSS tab you can write some CSS to override these margins and padding:

```css
.nautilus-list-view listview row { margin: 0px;  padding: 0; }
.nautilus-list-view #NautilusViewCell { padding: 3px; }
```

8. And verify it has the desired effect by switching back to the application window:

[image: nice Nautilus list spacing]

9. Finally once you have some working CSS, save it to `~/.config/gtk-4.0/gtk.css`, or if using GTK 3, the same file name under `~/.config/gtk-3.0`.